# Identifying the type of CBPeripheral before connecting

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth, thermal-printer, cbperipheral

I recently created an app that uses CoreBluetooth on iOS to connect to a thermal printer.
Everything is going just fine except for one thing.
I can see over 20 bluetooth devices but only one is a thermal printer.
Is there a way for me to know if this peripheral is a thermal printer or not before connection so that i can display/hide it ?
Thanks

Comment: Check the services it advertise?

Comment: i tried it before, for some reason the list of services is nil

Comment: What does it advertise? Could you isolate the advertisement data of the peripheral you are targetting?

Comment: how can i get the list before calling peripheral.discorverServices() since i tried that but did get the response in the delegate function didDiscoverServices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking about this backwards. You don't fetch the list of services and then decide whether to connect. You decide what services you want and scan for those.

When you call `scanForPeripherals(withServices:options:)`, you should almost always pass a list of services you support. If you're passing `nil`, then you're almost certainly calling it incorrectly unless you're building a general-purpose BLE scanner.

The same is true of `discoverServices(_:)`. You very rarely pass `nil` there. You pass the list of services you know how to deal with. The `.services` property is available as a convenience when you know you've already fetched the services, but it's rarely that useful. If you call `discoverServices(_:)` when it's unnecessary, the system will send you cached data immediately.

Comment: that was it, I've been working on connecting and printing properly for the better part of last week. the scanning part was one of my first code inserts thus i totally forgot that i can add arguments to the scan. thanks a lot